# Can someone point me to a good Canny edge detector implementation in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing

There is no JAI implementation of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [this](http://www.tomgibara.com/computer-vision/canny-edge-detector)?

Comment: I already tried it. It doesn't work very well. I wouldn't have asked if it could be found so easily by Google :)

Comment: Well, IIRC it's public domain.  What are the weaknesses?  They may be something fixable, and then you could re-release it PD, FL/OSS, or whatever.

Comment: If you update the question with particulars, I'll check back and respond to them.

Answer (score 0):

A good implementation, with source code, although probably not very efficient, is available as an [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) [Plugin](http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=plugin:filter:edge_detection:start).  It's possible to use that from your own code, without the ImageJ UI.

Another implementation of a steerable filter is also [here](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/demo/steerable/download.html).